# a4j:commandLink is erasing javascript from xhtml

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

As the title shows, when i click on the a4j:commandLink, the method executes perfectly and updates the table i need.

the problems is that the js of the page is disappearing after the a4j:commandLink post to the bean.

Edit: to bit a more clear, when i mean that the js disappears, what happens is that when i look for the javascript of the page in the Mozilla firebug, it doesn't show it.
Is this normal? what am I doing wrong? Any best approach for this?

the code is:

```
<h:panelGroup id="examplePanel" >
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty exampleBean.list}">
<table id="listDataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" 
    cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin-left: 0pt; width: 716px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>col1</th>
            <th>col2</th>
            <th>col3</th>                               
            <th class="shortCol">col4</th>
        </tr>       
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <a4j:repeat value="#{exampleBean.list}" rowKeyVar="itStatus" var="item">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h:outputText value="#{exampleBean.exampleShow(item)}" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <h:outputText value="#{exampleBean.exampleShow(item)}" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <h:outputText value="#{exampleBean.exampleShow(item)}" />
            </td>                  
            <td>
                <h:commandLink action="#{exampleShow(item)}" ></h:commandLink>
            </td>                               
        </tr>           
    </a4j:repeat>
    </tbody>
</table>
</h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:outputLabel value="* #{locale.name}:" />
<h:inputText value="#{exampleBean.exampleName}"
disabled="#{not exampleBean.edit}" id="exampleName" />

<div class="button search">
**<a4j:commandLink action="#{exampleBean.objetToTable}" value="#{locale.create}" render="exampleTurnPanel" ></a4j:commandLink>**
</div>
```

before this, i was using a h:commandLink with a f:ajax inside. But with this, the bean did not have the values, as the POST is never done. correct?

```
<h:commandLink action="#{exampleBean.objetToTable}"                     value="#{locale.create}">
<f:ajax execute="examplePanel" render="examplePanel" onevent="setExampleTableCss"/>                             </h:commandLink>
```

REGARDS.

Comment: It would be better if you move the JavaScript code outside your `exampleTurnPanel` component. If this doesn't work, isolate the problem and make sure it's `<a4j:commandLink>` fault (or it isn't).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly do you mean by disappearing JavaScript, but note that your `<a4j:commandLink>` updates `exampleTurnPanel` without refreshing the whole page. It means that new content of `exampleTurnPanel` is not affected by any JavaScript that you executed when loading the page.

If you have some JavaScript code that should affect contents of `exampleTurnPanel`, then you should place it inside `exampleTurnPanel`, in order to make it run at every update of the panel. Alternatively, you can explicitly call it after update using `oncomplete` attribute of `<a4j:commandLink>`.

In case of `<h:commandLink>` you need `<f:ajax event = "action" ... />`, though it shouldn't be different from `<a4j:commandLink>` (note, however, `onevent="setExampleTableCss"` in `<f:ajax>` - don't you need it in `oncomplete` of `<a4j:commandLink>`?).

Comment: i am using the a4j:command cuz i dont want to load again the whole page, just the table in it.
I will try to put the js inside the table to see thats happens.